# Create a scatter plot between multiple variables

Tags: r

Create a scatter plot between `flavanoids` and `phenols`. Have the point color and shape reflect the wine origin.

given:

```
wineurl <- paste("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/",
             "machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data", sep = "")
wine <- as_tibble(read.csv(file = wineurl, header = FALSE))
colnames(wine) <- c("origin", "alcohol", "acid", 
                       "ash", "alcalinity", "magnesium", 
                       "phenols", "flavanoids", "nonflavanoid",
                       "proanthocyanins","color.int", "hue",
                       "od", "proline")

wine <- wine %>% 
  mutate(origin = factor(origin))
```

Comment: This is phrased like a homework question. What have you tried so far, so you're not just trusting strangers on the internet to do your homework?

Comment: wine %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = flavenoids, y = phenols)

Comment: You can [edit] the question to include code, where it will be more legible. That sets up the basis for a plot; what have you tried as a next step to add any points? Take a look at ggplot tutorials if you're just getting started with it

Comment: This is obviously homework, and doesn't reflect much effort on the part of the OP. There's plenty of information in SO and elsewhere dealing with the color and shape of points in `geom_point`.

Answer (score 0):

try `ggplot(wine, aes(x = flavanoids, y = phenols, col=origin)) + geom_point()`.

`ggplot()` tells R to do a phenols vs flavanoids plot and use different color for different origin. and `geom_point()` tells R to do a scatter plot.

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer